# mysql find values und typs with same timestamp and insert in new table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

have a mysql database which looks like this:

```
|Timestamp  | Typ          | Value |
|01-01-2011 | temperature1 |  2|
|01-01-2011 | temperature2 | 3 |
|01-01-2011 | humidity1    | 98 |
```

I will transform this tabel to something lik this:

```
|Timestamp  | temperature1 | temperature2 | humidity1 | 
|01-01-2011 | 2            | 3            | 98        |
```

So i want for every typ a new column and all values with same timestamp in one row.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Timestamp, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.Typ = 'temperature1' THEN A.Value ELSE 0 END) AS temperature1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.Typ = 'temperature2' THEN A.Value ELSE 0 END) AS temperature2, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.Typ = 'humidity1' THEN A.Value ELSE 0 END) AS humidity1
FROM tableA A 
GROUP BY A.Timestamp;
```